# How to make multiple assignment of field values in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have jq command like this:

```
jq --arg ts "$TS" '.Date = $ts, .Marker.Date = $ts, .InfoFromTerminator.Timestamp = $ts'
```

but it appears to only replace the last item keeping the previous two as is. How do I rewrite the query to replace for all 3 parameters?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Comma is an operator in `jq`:

> Even the comma operator is a generator, generating first the values
>   generated by the expression to the left of the comma, then for each of
>   those, the values generate by the expression on the right of the
>   comma.

Changing multiple elements can be done by piping from one filter/assignment in to the next as follows:

```
jq --arg ts "$TS" '.Date = $ts | .Marker.Date = $ts | .InfoFromTerminator.Timestamp = $ts'
```

Comment: thanks for this. such a pain reading the official docs like an essay with no samples

Answer (score 1):

You can also use comma to assign a collection of properties to the same value:

```
jq --arg ts "$TS" '(.StartDate, .EndDate) = $ts'
```

This takes the list of path references on the left-hand side and updates them all to the new value.  This can be useful when the right-hand expression is more than a simple variable.

Example:

```
$ jq '(.a, .b) = "new value"' <<< '{"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c"}'
{
  "a": "new value",
  "b": "new value",
  "c": "c"
}
```