# Updating Multiple Elements to AWS Route 53 JSON Template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq

The following command updates 4 elements in an AWS Route 53 JSON Template by calling jq 4 times:

```
cat x.json | jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[].Action = "UPSERT"'|\
jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name = "host.domain"'|\
jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Type = "A"'|\
jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[].TTL ="300"'\|
jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[].Value ="10.120.0.1"'
```

Results in the following correct output:

```
{
  "HostedZoneId": "",
  "ChangeBatch": {
  "Comment": "",
  "Changes": [
  {
    "Action": "UPSERT",
    "ResourceRecordSet": {
      "Name": "host.domain",
      "Type": "A",
      "SetIdentifier": "",
      "Weight": 0,
      "Region": "",
      "GeoLocation": {
        "ContinentCode": "",
        "CountryCode": "",
        "SubdivisionCode": ""
      },
      "Failover": "",
      "TTL": 0,
      "ResourceRecords": [
        {
          "Value": "10.120.0.1",
          "TTL": "300"
        }
```

Is there a way to update all 4 fields with a single invocation of jq?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make multiple assignment of field values in jq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075323/how-to-make-multiple-assignment-of-field-values-in-jq)

Comment: The output shown is invalid JSON.  Also, if x.json is too long to include, then please provide a minimalist example.  Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pipe the filters of each invocation and you should get the same result.

```
$ jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[].Action = "UPSERT"
    | .ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Name = "host.domain"
    | .ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.Type = "A"
    | .ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[].TTL ="300"
    | .ChangeBatch.Changes[].ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[].Value ="10.120.0.1"' x.json
```

But there's a lot of repetition there just selecting the objects you wish to update.  You could update multiple values by merging an object with it with the values you want to set.

```
$ jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[] *= {
    Action: "UPSERT",
    ResourceRecordSet: {
        Name: "host.domain",
        Type: "A",
        ResourceRecords: [
            {
                TTL: "300",
                Value: "10.120.0.1"
            }
        ]
    }
}' x.json
```

However, the way merges work, only objects are recursively merged. Arrays have to be merged manually.  So if you want to preserve the items in your array (if there's more than 1), you'll have to adjust it to this:

```
$ jq '.ChangeBatch.Changes[] |= . * {
    Action: "UPSERT",
    ResourceRecordSet: {
        Name: "host.domain",
        Type: "A",
        ResourceRecords: .ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords | map(
            . * {
                TTL: "300",
                Value: "10.120.0.1"
            }
        )
    }
}' x.json
```

Comment: Since the template file only has 1 item in the array, your simple merge code works perfectly. I knew about "=" and "|=" but looks like I missed "*=". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following reasonably concise filter should do the job in a straightforward way, thanks to the power of `|=`:

`.ChangeBatch.Changes[] |=
  ( .Action = "UPSERT"
  | .ResourceRecordSet.Name = "host.domain"
  | .ResourceRecordSet.Type = "A"
  | .ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[].TTL ="300"
  | .ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords[].Value ="10.120.0.1"
  )`